# space of stability condition for an elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve. I want to understand why $\mathrm{Stab}(E)/\mathrm{Aut}(D^b(E))$ is a $\mathbb{C}^\times$-bundle over the moduli space $\mathbb{H}/\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ of elliptic curves.

It is known that the space of stability condition $\mathrm{Stab}(E)$ of an elliptic curve $E$ is given by the universal covering $\widetilde{GL^+}(2,\mathbb{R})$ of the general linear group $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})$ with positive determinant. I need to understand the following:

- Why $\widetilde{GL^+}(2,\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{H}$?
- Under the above identification, what is the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(D^b(E))$ on $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{H}$?

I am aware of the work of Mukai, saying the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(D^b(E))$ on $NS(E)\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ is given by $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$, but I want to understand this action in the above setting. Thank you in advance.